# In which cases does pronunciation change when a character ending in a consonant is followed by a character starting with a vowel?

Tags: pronunciation

(A rule I recall reading has affected how I pronounce words and I want confirmation on whether it is correct.)

When you have a 'character' that ends with a consonant and is followed 'character' that starts with a vowel, then the ending consonant is pronounced with the second 'character' instead of being at the end of the first 'character.'
Right?

---

For example,

(WITHIN A SENTENCE):

- 빨간 불일 때 길을 건너다. (To cross the street when it is red light.)

  - Would be pronounced as 빨간 "부릴" 때 "기를" 건너다.

(WITHIN A WORD)

- 입안자 (planner)

  - Would be pronounced as "이반자"

---

To what extent does this happen? Is it within a word that this is allowed or can it be whenever a character ending in a consonant is followed by a character starting with a vowel?

Comment: Korean ㅇ, when used as the final sound (받침), represents a single sound.  Don't let the Latin equivalent "ng" fool you: ㅇ cannot be divided into ㄴ+ㄱ.  Because it cannot start a syllable (at least in Korean), ㅇ will stay as 받침, so 고양이 will always be pronounced as 고양이.

Comment: Thanks for the info! The Latin equivalent did cause this confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically when `ㅇ` can changeable when there is `받침` in front of it.
I think there is exception for certain case, but most of time it will be like that.

For example, 
[image: doodoomchit]

Answer (score 3):

The first one `불일` being pronounced `부릴` is spot on.

As for the second one, I think the example given is too strong a pronunciation.  Say this sentence:

> Hang on tight.

It could not be pronounced:

> Han Kahn tight.

That would be too strong, you see.

You are on the right track with your thinking, though, yes, `받침` (consonant at the end of a syllable) is pronounced through a leading syllable's `ㅇ` as if it were the next syllable's leading consonant.

This is called `음의 동화`.  In fact, I've just found a site that explains the "variances" on this very well, I'll paste the pertinent content:

**from https://www.korean.go.kr :**

[질문]
장애음 뒤에 유음이 오는 경우 유음이 'ㄴ'으로 소리 나게 하고, 이 비음이 다시 앞에 오는 자음에 영향을 주어 비음화가 된다고 하는데요, 'ㄱ' 경우의 예로 독립 [동닙], 'ㅂ'의 예는 십리 [심니] 등이 있는데,\r 'ㄷ' 경우의 예를 찾을 수가 없는데,\r 그 예가 어떤 것이 있는지요?

[답변]
문의하신 음의 동화는 받침 'ㄱ, ㅂ'과 그 뒤에 연결되는 'ㄹ'의 발음에 관한 것입니다. 관련 규정인 '표준 발음법' 제5장 음의 동화, 제19항, 붙임 조항을 아래에 제시하니, 참고하시기 바랍니다. 받침 'ㄱ, ㅂ' 뒤에 연결되는 'ㄹ'도 [ㄴ]으로 발음한다. 막론[막논→망논] 백리[백니→뱅니] 협력[협녁→혐녁] 십리[십니→심니] (해설: 받침 'ㄱ, ㅂ' 뒤에서 'ㄹ'은 [ㄴ]으로 발음되는데, 그 [ㄴ] 때문에 'ㄱ, ㅂ'은 다시 [ㅇ, ㅁ]으로 역행 동화되어 발음된다. 예컨대 '막론(莫論)'은 '[막논]→[망논]'으로 발음되는 것이다.)